# How to autostart service in linux?

Tags: autostart

I've got [a program called `redshift`](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) that I would like to autostart when I log in. If I run "`redshift`" in a terminal (or `redshift &`) or via <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>, this will start it. I don't think it has an init script, so will adding "`redshift`" to my `.profile` file make it load at start? I suppose a cronjob set to `@reboot` could also work?

I think some programs need to be executed from a certain user environment, especially those affecting graphical elements? For example, if I SSH to a remote machine and try to open up a GUI program, obviously this will not be possible so it will fail. That's what I am trying to avoid in regards to *where* I execute this program from.

Comment: Do you mean to run it every time you login? Or at boot? How about ssh sessions, should the program start if you remotely login into your pc? If you are already logged in and open a new terminal, shoudl the program run again? Which distro are you on?

Comment: Whether it happens at boot or whether it happens when I login doesn't matter. I just want it to run whenever I start using my computer. Currently running Debian. And no, when I open a terminal, it should not run. This program should ideally start before I ever open a terminal (that was just an idea).

Answer (score 7):

redshift is not a system service; it works within your login session, as it needs to access the X11 server. So basically it should be autostarted the same way most graphical programs are:

#### Method 1

Add a file `redshift.desktop` to the XDG Autostart directory, `~/.config/autostart/`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Redshift
Exec=/usr/bin/redshift
```

This works with desktop environments that follow the XDG Autostart spec; this includes GNOME, KDE, Xfce, and many others. In some, it is editable through graphical interfaces (e.g. `gnome-session-properties` in GNOME).

#### Method 2

Add the following line...

```
redshift &
```

...to your `~/.xprofile`. This works with most display managers (gdm, kdm, lightdm, lxdm, sddm – not slim, however).

If you use the *startx* tool, `~/.xprofile` is not used by default, so you'll have to update your `~/.xinitrc` script instead – add the same line somewhere before starting the session manager.

#### Method 3

If you use a display manager like GDM, you might want to run the program before logging in, so that it'd apply to the login screen as well. How to do this varies between display managers, but in GDM it can be done by editing `/etc/gdm/Init/Default`. (Disclaimer: I haven't tried and this might be the wrong file.)

#### Things that will not work

- A system init script will not work since it runs independently of graphical sessions – it won't have the right `$DISPLAY` nor the right `$XAUTHORITY` set; if you hardcode those, it might end up trying to connect to the wrong display (e.g. you hardcode `DISPLAY=":0"` but your session happens to start at `:1`); and if you make it try all displays, the script is still very likely to start before *any* X11 display has been started.
- A `@reboot` cronjob will run as the right user (rather than needing to `su`/`sudo`), but otherwise it has all the same problems as system init scripts.

Comment: Alright, it looks like options 1 and 2 don't work and I don't know if I should try 3. I am running i3 which is a tiling window manager and not a common desktop manager.

Comment: Option 2 should certainly work, then.

Comment: Option 1 worked a treat, thank you! Ubuntu 18.04.